# Ravendb retrieve all documents in collection for reporting

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I need to retrieve all documents from a collection to dump it to an Excel file.

Using this seems to work

```
 var luceneQuery = Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Test.ReduceResult>("Test/ByTestData");
        var enumerator = Session.Advanced.Stream(luceneQuery);

        var obj = new List<Test.ReduceResult>();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            obj.Add(enumerator.Current.Document);
        }
```

This gives me all the results in the index.
But instead of index I want to retrieve all the documents in a collection (as the index does not contain all the information stored in the document).
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to be:

```
 var luceneQuery = Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Test.ReduceResult>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
    .WhereEquals("Tag", "Customers");
```

This will give you all customers.